# App Crashes in iOS 8 working in iOS 7

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, ios8

If I Push the View with Animation set to YES , the app crashes and below is the stack trace. and if I push to view without animation it is working correctly.

```
-[NewsFeedDetailView viewWillAppear:]
Nov 26 17:58:48  <Error>: -[NSNull length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x307c1400
Nov 26 17:58:48  <Warning>: Stack Trace:: (
        0   CoreFoundation                      0x225f8d7f <redacted> + 150
        1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x2fe57c77 objc_exception_throw + 38
        2   CoreFoundation                      0x225fe22d <redacted> + 0
        3   CoreFoundation                      0x225fc109 <redacted> + 712
        4   CoreFoundation                      0x2252d938 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 24
        5   UIKit                               0x25aa7a9b <redacted> + 38
        6   UIKit                               0x25b16d5b <redacted> + 66
        7   UIKit                               0x25b16d11 <redacted> + 84
        8   UIKit                               0x25b16c99 <redacted> + 400
        9   QuartzCore                          0x254f4681 <redacted> + 228
        10  QuartzCore                          0x254de0c1 <redacted> + 2068
        11  QuartzCore                          0x255bfb4d <redacted> + 52
        12  QuartzCore                          0x254dd8a5 <redacted> + 88
        13  QuartzCore                          0x254dd555 <redacted> + 1156
        14  QuartzCore                          0x254c1b1d <redacted> + 200
        15  QuartzCore                          0x254c17e1 <redacted> + 24
        16  QuartzCore                          0x254c11c7 <redacted> + 222
        17  QuartzCore                          0x254c0fd1 <redacted> + 324
        18  UIKit                               0x25a9c5f9 <redacted> + 1384
        19  CoreFoundation                      0x225bf5e7 <redacted> + 14
        20  CoreFoundation                      0x225be9fb <redacted> + 222
        21  CoreFoundation                      0x225bd079 <redacted> + 768
        22  CoreFoundation                      0x2250a981 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 476
        23  CoreFoundation                      0x2250a793 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
        24  GraphicsServices                    0x298e3051 GSEventRunModal + 136
        25  UIKit                               0x25afc981 UIApplicationMain + 1440
        26  W I T Party                         0x0014b1fd main + 220
        27  libdyld.dylib                       0x303f3aaf <redacted> + 2
    )
```

Please help me out with this

This is my viewWillAppear. I am just calling the super.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    NSLog(@"%s",__func__);

    [super viewWillAppear:NO];
}
```

Comment: Please show the relevant `viewWillAppear` method

Comment: OK, I was put off by `viewWillAppear` in the log, but I see now that it is just a log statement.  The trace says that you called `length` on `NSNull` - so perhaps start looking at where you use string length

Comment: You're calling super's viewWillApear: in wrong way. You should pass same `animated` parameter, i.e. super [super viewWillAppear:animated];

Comment: @arturdev No this does not solve my crash issue.

Comment: @Paulw11 My ViewDidLoad calls only Super Method, there is no way to check using string length etc.

Comment: you are calling length on null string lookout for a rouge string

Comment: @BindiManek it isn't crashing in viewWillAppear. My guess, and it is just a guess, is something is going to when attempting to i archive something - NSNull is stored in structures like arrays and dictionaries that can't hold nil. It seems that something is getting NSNull when it expects a string and not checking before accessing the length.  Have you tried setting an exception breakpoint?

Comment: Are you using third party frameworks? If so, check if they are up to date.

Comment: @BindiManek try using `[super viewWillAppear:animated];` i never face this kind of problem.. why you getting don't know..

Comment: I tried all the suggestions made. but none are working in my case. Even I have not faced such issue in my career. But somehow I am facing in these project

Comment: This link resolved my issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25919665/mysterious-crash-on-ios-8?rq=1. It was because I was using MapView

Comment: Yup.. It' working . . .